# Swap a few characters in a String in java?

Tags: java, string

I need to process a string for swapping a few characters for simple encryption.

```
 Input : ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
 Output: NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
```

In the above process I split the string into two and moved the first half into last half.

```
final int mid = (xyz.length()+1) / 2;
String[] spstr = {
    xyz.substring(0, mid),
    xyz.substring(mid),
};
String firstMix=spstr[1]+spstr[0];
System.out.println(firstMix);
```

Now, I need to swap the first two characters with the last two characters

```
Input : NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
Output: LMPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKNO
```

and also Swap the two characters immediately to the left of the middle of the string with the two characters that immediately follow them.

```
Input :  LMPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKNO
Output : LMPQRSTUVWXABYZCDEFGHIJKNO
```

The swap takes places between "YZAB" to "ABYZ" in the about input and output

What would be the best way to swap these characters effectively? I will have convert a lot of strings in this process. The string length is not constant in this case.

Comment: Side note - use a real encryption algorithm.

Comment: why don't you use `MessageDigest Class` of `java.security`!

Comment: Create a method that takes as arguments the string and the number of characters it should swap - and call it whenever you need.

Comment: Is your string a fixed length? If not, which characters are considered to be the *two characters immediately to the left of the middle of the string* for strings with an odd number of characters?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen My string will not be of fixed length.

Comment: @jdphenix I know, I could easily use an encryption algorithm! But my idea is to make a simple encryption algorithm

Comment: @JashJacob that's fine, just don't use it in a situation where you actually need encryption. Using it for learning or fun is okay.

Comment: Are these each individual steps, or does one follow the other?

Comment: @Smith_61 One follows the other

Comment: Can you change the Input/Output of each one to illustrate a single Input and the required Output after all steps.

Comment: @Smith_61 I've changed the Input/Output to illustrate a single input!

Comment: What is the case where there is an odd number of characters, or less than 4 characters for the last two steps?

Comment: @Smith_61 In case of odd number of characters -  first half being moved contains one more character than the last half. The string size will be greater than 4

Comment: And with the swapping of the two middle characters? Which ones are the middle characters when the length is odd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly correct, except for the undefined case of swapping the middle characters on a string length that is odd. Comments should be enough to understand the code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        char[] chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

        final int mid = ( chars.length + 1 ) / 2;


        System.out.println( "Mid: " + mid );
        System.out.println( "Start : " + new String( chars ) );

        // Pass one : Swap first half chars with last half chars
        if( ( chars.length % 2 ) == 1 ) {
            /* We swap the characters this way because the left half
             *  is one character longer than the right half. To avoid
             *  unnecessary copies we move the right character to
             *  the index before the left character and save the first
             *  character to be placed at the mid point
             */
            char first = chars[ 0 ];
            for( int l = 1, r = mid; r < chars.length; l++, r++ ) {
                chars[ l - 1 ] = chars[ r ];
                chars[ r ] = chars[ l ];
            }
            chars[ mid - 1 ] = first;
        }
        else {
            for( int l = 0, r = mid; r < chars.length; l++, r++ ) {
                swap( chars, l, r );
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Pass 1: " + new String( chars ) );

        // Pass two: Swap first two chars with last two chars
        swap( chars, 0, chars.length - 2 );
        swap( chars, 1, chars.length - 1 );

        System.out.println( "Pass 2: " + new String( chars ) );

        // Pass three: Swap middle 4 characters.
        swap( chars, mid - 1, mid + 1 );
        swap( chars, mid - 2, mid );

        System.out.println( "Pass 3: " + new String( chars ) );
    }


    public static void swap( char[] chars, int l, int r ) {
        char tmp = chars[ l ];
        chars[ l ] = chars[ r ];
        chars[ r ] = tmp;
    }
}
```

I chose to do the manipulation using character arrays to reduce the amount of objects created. This provides, in my opinion, the quickest solution for what you are asking for. When/if you clarify the undefined case I can edit the code to provide the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a method, convert strings into arrays, and use their index to manipulate and encrypt the characters.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try using the StringBuilder class.  It provides a lot of useful methods for manipulating Strings but avoid the problem of creating a lot of String objects in the process.

Answer (score 1):

### JAVACODE

***The Best way would be split the string into string array and do the
 processing as below as per your requirements***

> http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php For Testing the code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
        public class HelloWorld{

             public static void main(String []args){

                System.out.println("Hello World");

                String xyz= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                final int mid = (xyz.length()+1) / 2;

                String[] spstr = {
                    xyz.substring(0, mid),
                    xyz.substring(mid)
                };

                String firstMix=spstr[1]+spstr[0];

                String[] array = firstMix.split("");


                //Swap first and last two characters
                for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
                {
                   String temp= array[i];

                   array[i]=array[array.length-i];
                    array[array.length-i]=temp;

                }    



                String str1 = Arrays.toString(array); 
                str1 = str1.substring(1, str1.length()-1).replaceAll(",", "");

                //Swap  two characters left of middle with right of middle
                int  j=2;
                 for(int i=((array.length/2)-2);i<(array.length)/2;i++)
                {
                   String temp= array[i];
                   array[i]=array[array.length/2+j];
                   array[array.length/2+j]=temp;
                   j--;
                }   
                 String str2 = Arrays.toString(array); 
                  str2 = str2.substring(1, str2.length()-1).replaceAll(",", "");
                    System.out.println( firstMix);
                 System.out.println(str1);
                   System.out.println(str2);

             }
        }
```